# How to fill histogram with array data?

Tags: java, swing, graphics

I am having trouble getting my histogram to fill correctly.

I was given a large data file full of doubles that represented GPAs, about 5500 of them. I created a method to calculate the count, mean, and standard deviation of the data, however my last problem is to graph the data.

I am to make a histogram for each of the possible grades (12 of them) and graph them about the total of each grade.

I think I have coded the total for each grade correctly, but when it comes to actually drawing the histogram I cannot figure out the 4 arguments needed for fillRect.

I've been playing around with different variables, but nothing seems to get me close.

Any help is appreciated.

```
private static int[] gradeCounts(double[] stats) throws Exception{

   double stdv = 0;
   double sum = 0;
   double sum2 = 0;
   double variance = 0;

  Scanner fsc = new Scanner(new File("introProgGrades.txt"));

  while (!fsc.hasNextDouble())
     fsc.nextLine();

  int[] binCounts = new int[NUM_OF_GRADE_CATEGORIES];

  double x = 0;

  while (fsc.hasNextDouble()){
        stats[2]++;
     x = fsc.nextDouble();
     sum += x;
     sum2 += x * x;

     if (x == 0.0) 
      binCounts[0]++;
     else if (x == 0.6666667)
        binCounts[1]++;
     else if (x == 1.0)
         binCounts[2]++;
     else if (x == 1.3333333)
         binCounts[3]++;
     else if (x == 1.6666667)
         binCounts[4]++;
     else if (x == 2.0)
         binCounts[5]++;
     else if (x == 2.3333333)
         binCounts[6]++;
     else if (x == 2.6666667)
         binCounts[7]++;
     else if (x == 3.0)
         binCounts[8]++;
     else if (x == 3.3333333)
         binCounts[9]++;
     else if (x == 3.6666667)
         binCounts[10]++;
     else 
        binCounts[11]++;


     }

  stats[0] = sum/stats[2];
  variance = (stats[2] * sum2 - sum * sum) / (stats[2]*(stats[2]-1));
  stdv = Math.sqrt(variance);
  stats[1] = stdv;

 return binCounts;
```

}

What I am having trouble with:

```
  private static void plotHistogram(int[] binCounts){
  int max = Arrays.stream(binCounts).max().getAsInt();

  DrawingPanel panel = new DrawingPanel (800,800);
  Graphics2D g = panel.getGraphics();
   g.fillRect(0, 0, 800/binCounts.length,max);
```

}

I think I have to iterate through the data with a for loop, but it's the parameters of fillRect that I am clueless on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but when it comes to actually drawing the histogram I cannot figure out the 4 arguments needed for fillRect.

The [JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#fillRect(int,int,int,int)) are quite explicit in the properties and their meanings, it's just a box, with a position (x/y) and size (width/height)

> public abstract void fillRect​(int x,
>                                 int y,
>                                 int width,
>                                 int height) 
>   Fills the specified rectangle. The left and right edges of the rectangle are at x and x +
>   width - 1. The top and bottom edges are at y and y + height - 1. The
>   resulting rectangle covers an area width pixels wide by height pixels
>   tall. The rectangle is filled using the graphics context's current
>   color. 
> Parameters:
>  x - the x coordinate of the rectangle to be filled.
>   y - the y coordinate of the rectangle to be filled.
>  width - the width
>   of the rectangle to be filled.
>  height - the height of the rectangle to
>   be filled.
>
> I've been playing around with different variables, but nothing seems to get me close.

So, two things come to mind, the first comes from the JavaDocs above...

> The rectangle is filled using the graphics context's current
>   color

This is something that's easy to forget

The second is it seems that you misunderstand how painting works in Swing.

Painting in Swing has a very specific and well documented workflow.  The first thing you should do is go read [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) and [Painting in AWT and Swing](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) to get a better understanding of how painting works and how you should work with it.

There is never a good reason to call `JComponent#getGraphics`, apart from been able to return `null`, this is just a snapshot of the last paint cycle and will be wiped clean on the next paint pass (which may occur at any time for any number of reasons).

Instead, you will need a custom component and override it's `paintComponent` method instead.

You should then have a read through the [2D Graphics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/) trail to get a better understanding of how the API works and what features/functionality it can provide.

For example....

[image: Example]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Random rnd = new Random();
                int[] binCounts = new int[10];
                for (int index = 0; index < binCounts.length; index++) {
                    binCounts[index] = rnd.nextInt(100);
                }
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new DrawingPanel(binCounts));
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class DrawingPanel extends JPanel {

        private int[] binCounts;
        private int max;

        public DrawingPanel(int[] binCounts) {
            this.binCounts = binCounts;
            max = Arrays.stream(binCounts).max().getAsInt();

            System.out.println(max);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(800, 800);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            int barWidth = 800 / binCounts.length;
            for (int i = 0; i < binCounts.length; i++) {
                int barHeight = (int)((binCounts[i] / (double)max) * getHeight());
                // I personally would cache this until the state of the component
                // changes, but for brevity
                Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(i * barWidth, getHeight() - barHeight, barWidth, barHeight);
                g2d.setColor(Color.BLUE);
                g2d.fill(rect);
                g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                g2d.draw(rect);
            }
            g2d.dispose();

        }
    }

}
```